# python pip install -r requirements.txt problem

Tags: python, pip

I found this on github https://github.com/offish/twitchtube?fbclid=IwAR3XobKbDJ1_rPSd3hJOQWCiYb1Fwp6Z6EaronRihioWWKdswN_6T4Oq3Y4

I did everything and now i just need to run the bot! This is what i see when i try to use the bot!

```
X:\a>python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\a\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from twitchtube.config import *
  File "X:\a\twitchtube\config.py", line 15
    ROOT_PROFILE_PATH = "C:\Users\Mihai\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\jmey78di.Selenium"
                                                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

X:\a>python main.py
```

What i need to do next to make the bot work?

Update ** : This is how the things look after i put this on line 15 : ROOT_PROFILE_PATH = r"C:\Users\Mihai\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\jmey78di.Selenium"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BO9qe.jpg

The bot is working now!Ty for the help everyone!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHKyv.jpg

Comment: Try doing what your last error message said. Simply type 'python' into your cmd without anything after it. It will take you to the download page for python. Pip is a package manager for python(it installs libraries for you). When you download python, pip should get installed automatically as well

Comment: To fix the error after your update, make sure you are in the repository you downloaded. It should have a file named 'requirements.txt'. Cd there with your cmd and run the 'pip install -r requirements.txt'

Comment: The req file is in local disk X ,in folder "a". How i change directory to it? Im already on dir X right now

Comment: If you're on disk X already and the requirements.txt file is in folder 'a', you just type 'cd a'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download python from https://python.org. When in the installation, be sure to check the option that adds Python to PATH.

Comment: I already did that.And when i check that i saw i already have installed pip

Comment: your path maybe incorrect. If u have no idea with this, just reinstall

Comment: Environment variables usually don't update until you reboot(or just logout and back in) on your pc. Try that, if you're sure you installed python correctly and if you're sure it's in your path

Answer (score 0):

as @shamnad sherief said python needs to be in PATH, but you dont need to reinstall it:

press the win button>type remove add programs>in the search bar type python>click on python and click modify>in the window that shows up click modify>tick every box then press next>same: tick the add python to enviroment variables>click install.

Comment: Ty for the help!The box was checked anyway

Comment: you now need to cd to the full path of requirements.txt do `cd filepath`  then `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Ty!It worked now i just need to run the bot and  i have another error

Comment: please edit your question to explain the error.

Comment: i did now!i updated it

Comment: browse to main.py and open it with notepad, then go to line 15 and replace `ROOT_PROFILE_PATH = "C:\Users\Mihai\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\jmey78di.Selenium"` 
with: 
`ROOT_PROFILE_PATH = r"C:\Users\Mihai\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\jmey78di.Selenium"`

Comment: line 15 was empty. I just put there now what you told me to and i have exactly the same error

Comment: oh i am sorry the problem isnt in main.py but in X:\a\twitchtube\config.py so try doing the same thing on that file.

Comment: ty so much for the help now it s working. I had to put what you told me in config and not in the main.py but it's all fine!Ty so much for the help

Comment: i put this ROOT_PROFILE_PATH = r"C:\Users\Mihai\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\jmey78di.Selenium"
in config and it worked